# Cannot seem to increment users input by +1 and print it back out to the screen x86 Assembly, AT&T syntax 64bit registers

Tags: assembly, gcc, 64-bit, x86-64, att

So, I have attached my code below which basically asks a user for a numerical input, once the users supplies the number the code should add 1 to it and print it back out to the screen. However, this does not happen and instead the number just gets displayed as its original value.

Can someone explain how to solve?

```
 .data
    text1: .asciz "Assignment 2 - in/out \nPlease enter a number\n"
    text2: .asciz "\n Your number +1 = "
 
.bss
    number: .skip 8       #reserve 8 bytes for the users number
    
 
.text
.global main
main:
 
    call _printText1        #sub routine to print assignment name to screen
    call _getNumber         #sub routine to take number from the user
    call _printText2        #sub routine to print the text associated with the users number
 
    movq $60, %rax          #Basic exit sequence for the program
    movq $0, %rdi           #clears data in rdi
    syscall
    
_printText1:                #sub routine to print assignment name to screen
    movq $1, %rax           #move 0 into rax
    movq $text1, %rdi       #load my string into rdi register
    call printf             # printf function prints data within rdi register
    movq $0, %rdi
    ret
 
_getNumber:                 #sub routine to take number from the user
    movq $0, %rax           #set to 0 for input
    movq $0, %rdi
    movq $number, %rsi
    inc %rsi
    movq $8, %rdx
    syscall
    ret                     #exit the sub-routine

    
_printText2:                #sub routine to output the text associated with the users number +1
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $text2, %rsi
    movq $27, %rdx
    syscall
    ret
```

Comment: Your `_getNumber` increments the address of the number, and it even does that before reading the input so it has no chance of working. Delete the `inc %rsi` and use `incb number` after the `syscall`.

Comment: _getNumber:
    movq $0, %rax          
    movq $0, %rdi
    movq $number, %rsi
    movq $8, %rdx
    syscall
       # inc %rsi
       # inc $number
    ret

Comment: I have tried that also but when i include incb number after the syscall it gives an error saying incorrect operand for inc

Comment: You used a `$` sign which you must not as that is the address. Use `incb number` exactly as I said.